# Fourier Transform of $\exp{(ax(1-\log x ))}$

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

I was wondering if there exists a closed form solution for the Fourier transform of

$$
\exp{(ax(1-\log x ))},
$$

where $a$ is a positive constant, and clearly $x > 0$ (we consider the function to be zero for $x<0$).  For larger values of $a$ (say 25 or so) the function is quite similar to a shifted Gaussian.

If there exists a closed form solution, how do I calculate it?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $e^{ax(1-\log x)}=x^{-ax}e^{ax}$

Comment: Do you imply that there exists no closed form solution because of $x^{-ax}$?

Comment: @AlexSilva, sorry, I dont see the connection to my problem. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @AlexSilva, my fourier transform then becomes $\int_0^\infty x^{-ax}e^{x(a-i\xi)}dx$. The Exponential Integral is defined as $Ei(x) = -\int_{-x}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt$. I fail to see which substitution connects both equations...

Comment: Sorry @user369114! I thought your expression was $exp(a(x - log(x)))$. I don't think your FT has a closed form. The integral is not simple!